# Evenly Distributing Arrary Elements Across Multiple Columns in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

first time poster, long time reader.

Apologies if this is hard to follow.

I have a spreadsheet which has a list of first names and last names. What I am wanting to do is take all of the first names which have the same last name and place them, evenly(ish) and separated by a comma, into the 3 reference columns in the same spreadsheet for example;

[Example of Completed Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Vcr.jpg)

I would like to do this in VBA because there are 200+ names and growing, and later the code will use this information to create and populate more workbooks.

So far, what I have works for all last names which have 3 or less first names (ie; one per column) but I cannot get it to work for last names where there are more than 3 first names.

My thought was to read all of the names into an array, split out the elements which have more than 3 names into another array, join these together separated by a comma, to then be transferred to the relevant column on the sheet.

However for some reason, I cannot get it to output more than one name into the column.

I have had a few attempts at this, but this is my latest attempt;

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim m As Long

Dim namesPerCol As Long

Dim strLastNameMatches As String
Dim arrNames() As String
Dim arrMultiNames(3) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    'Finds the last row with data in it
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Sort the Columns
Columns("A:E").Sort key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=xlYes

'Loop through the LastNames
For i = 2 To lngLastRow
    'Second loop through the LastNames
    For j = 2 To lngLastRow
        'If the last name matches
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value Then
            'If the cell is empty then
            If Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
                'Place the name in colA into colC
                Range("C" & i).Value = Range("A" & j).Value
            Else
                'If the cell is not empty, then place a comma and space and then the value from colA
                Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i).Value & ", " & Range("A" & j).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 2 To lngLastRow
    strLastNameMatches = Range("C" & i).Value
    arrNames = Split(strLastNameMatches, ", ")
    If UBound(arrNames) > 2 Then
        namesPerCol = UBound(arrNames) / 3
        For l = 0 To 1
            For k = LBound(arrNames) To namesPerCol
                arrMultiNames(l) = arrNames(k) & ", "
            Next k
        Next l

        For m = LBound(arrMultiNames) To UBound(arrMultiNames)
            Select Case m
                Case 0
                    Range("C" & i).Value = arrMultiNames(m)
                Case 1
                    Range("D" & i).Value = arrMultiNames(m)
                Case 2
                    Range("E" & i).Value = arrMultiNames(m)
            End Select
        Next m

    Else
        For j = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)
            Select Case j
                Case 0
                    Range("C" & i).Value = arrNames(j)
                Case 1
                    Range("D" & i).Value = arrNames(j)
                Case 2
                    Range("I" & i).Value = arrNames(j)
            End Select
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Apologies for the poor quality coding, I will work on tiding it up once it is all working.

Any help I can get to get this code splitting out the names evenly across the three columns will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you grouping together two names in each column - why not just have as many columns as there are names e.g. C1 = John, D1 = David, E1 = George, F1 = Sarah, G1 = Mary, H1 = Elizabeth? Is that an acceptable solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained, this data will be copied by other users into another application (not managed by us) which only has 3 reference fields, so I have to split the names across the three fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task might be simpler if you could store your data into a more tree-like structure. There are many ways to do this; I've used the `Collection` object as it's easy to handle an unknown number of items. Basically, there are collections within a collection, ie one collection of first names for each last name.

The sample below uses very rudimentary distribution code (which is also hard-coded to a split of 3), but the point is that iterating through and down the tree is far simpler:

```
Dim lastList As Collection, firstList As Collection
Dim lastText As String, firstText As String
Dim data As Variant, last As Variant, first As Variant
Dim output() As Variant, dist(1 To 3) As Long
Dim str As String
Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long

'Read data into an array
With Sheet1
    data = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
End With

'Create lists of unique lastnames containing the firstnames
Set lastList = New Collection
For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1)

    firstText = CStr(data(r, 1))
    lastText = CStr(data(r, 2))

    Set firstList = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set firstList = lastList(lastText)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If firstList Is Nothing Then
        Set firstList = New Collection
        lastList.Add firstList, lastText
    End If

    firstList.Add firstText

Next

'Write results to sheet
ReDim output(1 To UBound(data, 1) - 1, 1 To 3)
For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
    lastText = CStr(data(r, 2))
    Set firstList = lastList(lastText)
    'Calculate the distribution
    dist(3) = firstList.Count / 3 'thanks @Comitern
    dist(2) = dist(3)
    dist(1) = firstList.Count - dist(2) - dist(3)
    i = 1: c = 1: str = ""
    For Each first In firstList
        str = str & IIf(i > 1, ", ", "") & first
        i = i + 1
        If i > dist(c) Then
            output(r - 1, c) = str
            i = 1: c = c + 1: str = ""
        End If
    Next
Next
Sheet1.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```

Comment: You can't floor the distribution with `dist(3) = Int(firstList.Count / 3)` - it prevents it from rounding.  It should be simply `dist(3) = firstList.Count / 3`.  Why `On Error Resume Next` and a `Collection` when you can just use a `Scripting.Dictionary` and `.Exists(key)`?

Comment: @Comintern, yes, good point re `Int`, thanks, I'll edit answer. As for `Collection`, looking at OP's code, it seemed he was a fairly new coder, so I thought I'd avoid introducing the concept of binding - could have late bound it, but then he'd have lost intellisense. Agree, though, that `Dictionary` would be the obvious route.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. This worked great for the task. I am a newish coder for work and typically I only learn the bits I need at the time I need them - which results in more than a few gaps in my knowledge. On that note, do you have any suggestions for ways the original code could be improved?

Comment: @ItsNotGoneWell, the first part of your code is fine; the second part is where you're hitting problems. Partly it's your syntax (ie the array building loop doesn't run to 3 and the distribution logic is flawed), but partly it's the logical structure. Eg, writing the 'CSV' values into column "C" and then splitting them and rewriting them to "C:E" seems unnecessary, and running your full algorithm on the same names seems inefficient. My preference is still to go for a hierarchical data structure - you could do this with arrays; just assign firstname arrays to each element of your lastname array.